# Remove page number from title

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, page

I am dealing with the following problem. Basically I would like to remove the page number from title slide.
My code looks as follows (MWE):

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % nebo zkuste Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw,...
  \usecolortheme{default} % nebo zkuste albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % nebo zkuste serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\newenvironment{squareenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]}}{}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] % to number

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newtcbox{\mybox}{blank, on line, opacitytext=0.5}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\theoremstyle{plain} % insert bellow all blocks you want in italic
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,trees,overlay-beamer-styles}


\tikzset{
every node/.style={draw,text width=2cm,drop shadow},
style1/.style= {rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, thin,align=center,fill=green!30},
style2/.style= {rectangle, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center,fill=green!60},
style3/.style= {rectangle,thin,align=left,fill=pink!60},
style4/.style= {fill=#1, minimum height=9ex, anchor=base},
svisible on/.style={alt=#1{}{opacity=0,every shadow/.style={opacity=0}}}
}


\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\highlightred}[1]{%
  \colorbox{red!50}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
  
  \newcommand{\highlightyellow}[1]{%
  \colorbox{yellow!50}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
  
  \newcommand{\highlightgreen}[1]{%
  \colorbox{green!50}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
  
  \newcommand{\highlightblue}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue!50}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
  
  \newcommand{\highlightpink}[1]{%
  \colorbox{pink!40}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
  
    \newcommand{\highlightorange}[1]{%
  \colorbox{orange!40}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
  
    \newcommand{\highlightcyan}[1]{%
  \colorbox{cyan!40}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
  
    \newcommand{\highlightbrown}[1]{%
  \colorbox{brown!40}{$\displaystyle#1$}}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, quotes, tikzmark,shapes}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%%% PAGE NUMBERING
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{page number appendix}
{%
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertpagenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number appendix]%
  \renewcommand*{\insertpagenumber}{%
    \Roman{framenumber}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\indep}{\perp \!\!\! \perp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


%definice matematických prostředí
\newtheorem{veta}{Věta}
\newtheorem{lema}[veta]{Lemma}

\title{At the intersection between Machine Learning and Econometrics: theory and applications}
\author{\underline{Nutarelli Federico}}
\institute{IMT for Advanced Studies Lucca}
\date{}
\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{Logo_eng.png}
}
\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]{Overview}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now the key here is %%% PAGE NUMBERING

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{ \hspace{1em}    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber }
```

I think that there is something that contrasts because the output actually looks like without page numbering for main slides and roman numbering for appendix (which is wanted). How can I produce numbering also for the main part but without numbering title page?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this as an example:

***1)***

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
```

***2)***

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\AtBeginSection[]{%
  \begin{frame}[plain]
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
} 

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]